# Paypal REST API and Transaction Fees

Tags: paypal

Does the new Paypal REST API support collecting transaction fees similar to Stripe:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collecting-fees

Answer (score 0):

REST apis currently do not have that option, the only additional fee is for shipping, other than tax.

Transaction amount details (subtotal, tax, shipping), which adds up to total.

```
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD",
        "details":{
          "subtotal":"7.41",
          "tax":"0.03",
          "shipping":"0.03"
        }
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
```

The classic APIs had a handling charge option so it is possible that the feature may be added to REST in the future as well.